# Access multiple elements with ID from within a node, but also with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to retrieve all elements who's **ID ends with "_inputError"** from **within a specific element**! AND also , I need to retrieve only the inputError that **has class 'b-block'** set.. How would I do this using javascript/jquery ?

I know I can get my form node with: `var formNode = $("#frm1");`

I know I can get ALL elements with ID ending, but this will get them all, which isn't quite what I need: `var inputErrors = $("[id$=_inputError]");`.

How do I mix'em all together as to retrieve only the input errors with 'd-block' class from within a specified form node ?

Cheers!

UPDATE: This seems to work for me:

```
var inputErrors = $("[id$=_inputError].d-block");
console.warn(inputErrors[0]);
```

It'll retrieve all inputError with class .d-block. However, I've yet to find how to do this check ONLY from a selected form element id, instead of the hole page. (I can have multiple forms on a single page!)

Comment: jQuery selectors follow CSS rules, so to filter by a parent element select that then leave a space: `var inputErrors = $(".d-block [id$=_inputError]");`

Comment: Thx for your input, but it's not working for me... I can individualy get all elements with class '.d-block' OR I can get all element with ID ending with 'inputError', but combining like you proposed doesn't work..

Comment: In which case we need to see a working example of the HTML and JS as I can guarantee you that what I suggested works fine.

Comment: I've updated the post with partial solution...

Comment: Ah, apologies. I misread the question that you wanted to find elements within that which had a class. What you've got there, `[id$=_inputError].d-block` will work fine, although it's not clear what you mean by 'I've yet to find how to do this check ONLY from a selected form element id'. Add the id to the selector where needed...?

Comment: That will work, BUT it'll retrieve all inputErrors in ALL forms in page! As I said, I need to limit the search from within an element (i.e. formid). On some pages, I have tables with each row being a form.. So need to check for these on 'per form' basis..

Comment: try `var inputErrors = $("#frm1 [id$=_inputError].d-block");` it worked when I checked

Comment: Confirmed! It works :) Thanks a million!

Comment: That's what I suggested in my first comment :)

Answer (score 0):

To help others if it can, here's the final solution and why I needed this:

Essentially, I get a response back from an ajax post like so:

```
{
  type: 2,
  formid: 'frmProfile',
  fields: {
    username: "Invalid username!", 
    email: "Invalid email!"
  }
}
```

I loop my response.fields to show the individual errors under each failed inputs.

I then needed to find a way set focus on the first failed input! Because my fields are NOT 0-indexed based, I could not simply set the focus on the first field in the array! They are 'randomly' looped through!

Therefor, I decided to get all input errors that we're showing (id=*_inputError and with class d-block). The first one in the returned array is in fact the first input error! So, I use its ID to determine the corresponding input name and set focus to it:

```
var inputErrors = $("#" + response.formid + " [id$=_inputError].d-block");
var firstInputError = inputErrors[0].id.replace(/_inputError$/, ''); // get just the name of the failed input! Its name/id should be the same as <name>_inputError!

document.getElementById(firstInputError).focus();
```

This seems to do the trick for me ;) Hopefully, this can serve ideas to others.

Thanks for your help folks!
P